# User Control With Image To bind in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, user-controls

I want to make a user control that contains Image control and I want to bind its source with a url of image. How to do this in the user control XAMl and CS code and how to use this user control and bind its dependency property ?

Comment: if someone help you learn to mark as an answer , your history shows you have never done

Answer (score 0):

You could have the `Image` control like this, which you could bind the `source` to it:

```
<Image Width="75" Height="75" Source="{Binding thumbUrl}" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

For more you could refer these:

[Image databinding XAML, Silverlight, C#, Windows Phone 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765842/)

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/data-binding-images-in-windows-phone

Hope it helps!

Comment: @AbdullahEl-Menawy In the xaml page, you can go and create an <Image> control. Within that apply all the properties which you need. If you're gonna bind the url you should have the view model, for that please refer those links I've mentioned.

Comment: The problem is that I want to bind the image in a User Control

Comment: What do you exactly meant bt User Control?

Comment: UserControl : where I can have some controls that I can use to help me do something quickly. Something like to show posts in like facebook posts

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user control by,

(i)Right click the project tile in Solution Explorer and then select Add->New Item

(ii)Select Windows Phone User Control from the pop up windows, set the name that you want to use

(iii)Add the following code inside the XAML part of the user control

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <TextBlock Text="My User Control" FontSize="34"/>
     <Image x:Name="Image1" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Define a property in your Model,

```
public Uri ImageUrl { get; set; }
```

and bind it to your Image

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://Abundantcode.com/image.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)
Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Now you can use UserControl anywhere you want,

```
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl" />
```

Comment: but I want to set the URI when using this user control in a Long List Selector

Comment: This how you bind a image uri to a user control, it does not matter wherever it belongs to, edit your question if you want more perfect answer

Comment: I mean in this line of code : <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl" />
How can i bind the ImageURL property ?