# How can I convert the path of an image into stream in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have an image saved in a local folder of my application. I save it into Isolated Storage. I am giving the image path to a BitmapImage variable. How to convert it to Stream. Or is there any other way to get the image to save it into Isolated storage in WindowsPhone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the answer is similar to this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400624/windows-phone-7-silverlight-binding-image-from-the-isolatedstorage

Comment: This works - 

     var sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(LocalFolderImagePath, UriKind.Relative));
     Stream  imageStream = sr.Stream;

Answer (score 1):

i think u can use a dictionary with string and object i.e.,

```
 dictionary<string,object>
```

or string and image

```
dictionary<string,Image>
```

and store your images, where in key is the name of the image (unique to each image in the Dictionary) and object can be a image again or directly store images.